# Chrome "Clear Cookie" setting randomly turns on

Tags: google-chrome

In Chrome there is a setting "Clear cookies and site data when you close all windows", which I normally have switched off.

But, randomly, the setting seems to switch itself ON. Which means, without knowing, I lose all my cookies when I close chrome.

What/Who is it switching it on? How to I stop this happening.

[image]

Windows 10
Chrome Version 108.0.5359.126 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Answer (score 0):

Chrome settings will never change by accident! It must have been altered by some program you install or some website you allow to change the settings.

Comment: Yes, I know that. How do I track down the culpruit?

Comment: Hi @Ken! You can check your installed programs and uninstall unwanted them, Or check violence access by some antivirus or security guard applications.